# Cobordant of Dold manifold and Wu manifold via fibered classifying spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, fibration, cobordism

**Background**: I think, Dold manifold and Wu manifold are 5-dimensional manifolds which are [cobordant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) to each other via 5-dimensional bordism group:
$$
\Omega^{SO}_5.
$$

---

Literally, cobordism theories are represented by Thom spectra $MG$: given a group $G$, the Thom spectrum is composed from the Thom spaces $MG_n$ of the standard vector bundles over the classifying spaces $BG_n$.
So we  may also say that
Dold manifold and Wu manifold are 5-dimensional manifolds which are [cobordant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) to each other via 5-dimensional bordism group
$$
\Omega^{}_5(BSO),
$$
where $BSO$ is the classifying space of $SO$.  Here we can simply take the special orthogonal group $SO=SO(5)$ since we are in 5-dimension.

Consider the following new classifying space $BG'$ constructed from the fibrations
$$
K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)\to BG' \to BSO,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)\to BG' \to K(SO,1),
$$
where $K(\mathbb{Z}_2,2)$ is the [Eilenberg–MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space).
The possible classes of fibrations are classified by Postinikov classes 
$[\omega]\in H^3(BSO,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2.$ So there are actually two different fibrational classifying space $BG'$.

Let us consider these two new classifying space $BG'$ (denoted as $BG'_1$  and $BG'_2$.)

**Questions**:

> 1. Are Dold manifold and Wu manifold (5-dimensional manifolds) which are [cobordant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism) via 5-dimensional bordism group:
>      $$
>    \Omega^{}_5(BG')?
>    $$
>      for either $BG'_1$  and $BG'_2$.
> 2. If the above answer is yes, does it mean that (Dold manifold) $\#$ (Wu manifold) is null-bordant via $\Omega^{}_5(BG')?$ for which $BG'_1$  and $BG'_2$?